# Taking value of Html.TextBox

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to take the entered value of a textbox to a variable in jquery.

```
@Html.TextBox("username", @Views.Resource.EnterEmail, new { @class = "cssclass" })
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Login").click(function () {

        var u = ??;
        var p = ??;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/User/Login",
            data: "username=" + u + "&password=" + p

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: something like $('#username').text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your inputs unique ids:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "username", 
    @Views.Resource.EnterEmail, 
    new { @class = "cssclass", id = "username" }
)
```

and then:

```
$('#Login').click(function () {
    var u = $('#username').val();
    var p = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/User/Login',
        data: { username: u, password: p }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But a **much better** alternative is to subscribe to the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the corresponding form instead of the click event of some button:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
```

where `loginForm` is an unique id that you would give to the form that contains those input fields.